# ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Tags: php, html, toast

I´ve been trying to show toast notifications on my page with [toastr.js](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr), but this error keep showing:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVL32.png)

I already included jquery and both js and css, but didn´t anyway, this is the code:

> EDIT: when i try to show the toast notifications directly on the html code, it works fine, but when i call them inside of the php function, the error keep appearing

```html
<?php

// WHEN I TRY TO SHOW THE ALERT WITH THIS PHP FUNCTION, IT DOESN'T WORKS!

function cms_alert($message, $type) {
 switch ($type) {
  case "info":
   echo "<script>toastr.info('INFO!');</script>";
   break;
  case "success":
   echo "<script>toastr.success('SUCCESS!');</script>";
   break;
  case "warning":
   echo "<script>toastr.warning('WARNING!');</script>";
   break;
  case "error":
   echo "<script>toastr.error('ERROR!');</script>";
   break;
 }
}
?>

    <?php

    // THE ERROR IS HAPPENING HERE!

} else {
 // Senão, mostra a página de login
 if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = ($_POST['password']);

  // Caso deixe todos os campos em branco, uma mensagem de erro é mostrada
  if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
   cms_alert("Preencha todos os campos!", "error");
  } else {
   if ($username == $admin_username and $password == $admin_password) {
    // Usuário digitou login e senha corretos
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
   } else {
    // Usuário digitou login e senha incorretos
    cms_alert("Nome/senha esta incorreto!", "error");
   }
  }
 }

 ?>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>tinyCMS - Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <center>
  <h1><a href="/"><?php echo $site_name; ?></a></h1> <!-- Mostra o titulo do site -->
  <h5><?php echo $site_description; ?></h5> <!-- Mostra a descrição do site -->

  <hr/>

  <h4>Digite seu login e senha para continuar:</h4>

  <!-- LOGIN -->
  <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" />
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha" />
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
 </center>

 <hr/>

 <?php echo $site_footer_admin; ?>

</body>

<!-- WHEN I USE THE CODE DIRECTLY ON THE HTML FILE, IT WORKS FINE! -->

<script>toastr.error('Hello World!');</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have extra spaces in your URL, which probably make it 404.

Comment: I fixed the url, but still not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You have whitespace in the link which causes a 404.
2. You put the javascript in a stylesheet tag and the CSS in a javascript tag.
3. You must include jQuery.

Try this:

```
<?php
function cms_alert($message, $type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case "info":
            echo "<script>toastr.info('INFO!');</script>";
            break;
        case "success":
            echo "<script>toastr.success('SUCCESS!');</script>";
            break;
        case "warning":
            echo "<script>toastr.warning('WARNING!');</script>";
            break;
        case "error":
            echo "<script>toastr.error('ERROR!');</script>";
            break;
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <?php cms_alert("Hello World!", "success"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a **lot!** (but the toast notifications are not working when i call with php, just html, any ideas what is causing it?)

Comment: Check the console, I tested the above code it works fine, (except SUCCESS is shown not Hello World!), you would just need to set $message into the js string, also check for `'` in your text as it will break unless you use htmlentities or addslashes.

Comment: The console just keeps showing the same error, when i put `<script>toastr.error('Hello World!');</script>` directly on html code, it works, but when i put `echo "<script>toastr.error('Hello World!');</script>";` on the php function, nothing happen, and the error keep appearing on the console

Comment: @HenriqueHBR You must call the function. Update it with whats not working.

Comment: @HenriqueHBR As your directly echo'ing from the function you cant call it before, else its going to echo out in the head of the document, you should return from it and store the value in a variable.